# Snowflake Email alert regarding table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way we can receive email alerts from snowflake, in case where a table is not updated for a long time, suppose we have sql query :

```
select table_schema,
       table_name,
       last_altered as modify_time
from information_schema.tables
where last_altered < DATEADD(DAY, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
      and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
order by last_altered desc;
```

which return all the tables which are last modified after 30 days from today and we want them in a email notification

I have tried going through documents of snowflake but not able to find any thing, We want Email notification of all the tables that were not updated in past 30 days. Is there any Stored Procedure or any thing I can use to to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For periodic checks [Setting Up Alerts Based on Data in Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/alerts):

> To do this, you can set up a Snowflake alert. A Snowflake alert is a schema-level object that specifies:
>
> - **A condition that triggers the alert** (e.g. the presence of queries that take longer than a second to complete).
> - **The action to perform when the condition is met** (e.g. send an email notification, capture some data in a table, etc.).
> - **When and how often the condition should be evaluated** (e.g. every 24 hours, every Sunday at midnight, etc.).

Sending email could be performed with [Sending Email Notifications](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/email-stored-procedures) and [SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures/system_send_email)